# Are there BJTs based on metal-semiconductor junctions?

Tags: bjt, schottky

So, I know that the fundamental part of a BJT is having a very thin base region that allows minority carriers to diffuse through it before they recombine. It seems to me, then, that it should be possible to use two back-to-back Schottky junctions just as effectively as back-to-back pn junctions--but "Schottky transistor" means something entirely different.

Are there any transistors, or is one even possible, comprising a thin layer of semiconductor sandwiched between two metals? I can see some obvious manufacturing difficulties, so I can certainly understand if none actually exist, but I am curious whether it would be possible.

Comment: Do you mean point contact transistors?

Comment: ...this _is_ what a point-contact transistor is, isn't it? I somehow managed to completely forget that those existed!